# MVP Model - Where to call events that are triggered from others events and not by the user (View)

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, mvp

I have an Android App that interacts with a Irc server where I'm trying to use the MVP model. There is the View layer (`Activity`, `Fragments`). A Model layer that is composed by a bunch of Runnable executable classes (called UseCases) that doing one specific thing and provides asynchronous callbacks. Most of this Use Cases are started by the user from View layer.

For example: the user trigger the `Button` to connect to server. Then it call the Presenter, that call the Model, that returns to Presenter success or error via callbacks. Then Presenter notify back the View.

But there are cases that do not need user interaction. For example, if user want to join an irc channel, he trigger a call that is executed by JoinChannelUseCase and then a callback return to `ChannelPresenter` the user list of that channel. I get this user list and search for a specific user in the list and perform a action to this user. This action is not trigger by the user, so It don't need to come from view. But I don't know exactly where to put this code. If I put into `ChannelPresenter` in the Join method callback, It look weird. Below there is a snipet from `ChannelPresenter` class that explain it better.

ChanelPresenter snipet:

```
@Override
public void join(final String channel) {
    joinChannelUseCase.execute(channel, new JoinChannelUseCase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ChannelInfo channelInfo) {
            channelView.showChannelJoined(channelInfo.getChannelName() + channelInfo.getUsers().size());
            //call another use case acting in the list of users returned.
             // this code is to be here? 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            channelView.showChannelJoinError(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

My question is where to trigger this type of operations that are triggered by another event (in this case the success to join channel).

Comment: see this https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm

Comment: Follow the link http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments. I implemented my functionality based on Antonio Leiva article and this example project: https://github.com/pedrovgs/EffectiveAndroidUI. My doubt is not about the overall concept our implementation of clean architecture, but how to deal in the cases where I need to nested calls to different UseCases that the second call don't part from User, like in the example I paste, where I need to do another call to UseCase layer after the joinChannel returns me the list of users of channel. I don't know if I made myself clear, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right.

If you feel more confortable, make types and instances for these callbacks. This makes the code cleaner in my opinion.

In case you would be interested in "clean architecture" (as I strongly recommend), take a look to a [prezi I did for a workshop](https://prezi.com/zkotn_cvj2pv/android-clean-architecture-workshop/) (this workshop was for beginners in Android and it had a 70% of practice, so you won't find so much code).

Other extremelly interesting references here:

Here you are [good theory](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/)

And a good [implementation sample](http://androcode.es/2015/02/un-stack-productivo-para-el-desarrollador-android-1-arquitectura/). A part is in Spanish, maybe Google Translate can help you.